# Can a WPF ScrollViewer PageDown be configured to scroll past the last item?

Tags: wpf

I would like the ScrollViewer PageDown to scroll past ALL items on the current page. This is only relevant at the end of the list. So if there are 60 lines per page and 80 lines total I want PageDown to show only 20 lines and blank space after. How would I go about this? I am using an ItemsControl to hold a list of objects that needs to be scrolled by page only. I will include the whole XAML code block for reference.

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="MyScrollViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" CanContentScroll="True">
   <ItemsControl x:Name="MyItemsControl" Margin="1" Background="Transparent" 
                 ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyObjectList}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="4,2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="1">
               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="235"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyTimeStr}"/>
               <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding MySystemStr}"/>
               <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding MyMessage}"/>
            </Grid>
         </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The C# code behind uses a Button click event to call:

```
MyScrollViewer.PageDown();
```